# Report Builder TeeChart

Tags: report, reportbuilder3.0

I'm developing a Report to one of our customers, using two linked tables, and grouping it on the report by one of the columns.

On the header of the group i need to insert a DPTeeChart, that shows the flow of cash on that group.

The grouping works well, gets all the right data, but the DPTeeChart gets the value of the whole Pipeline, and prints the same, overloaded chart over and over, for each group.

Is there anyway i can print it correctly?

Or is there anyway i can clear the graphic on each groupBreak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the Digital Metaphors staff about the problem, they said it's because this operation is not supported on the version I use.
`Current Version: 15.04 Build 145`